How to use template images to match and cutout scanned image files?
I am a FUJIFILM instax player.
I put the photos I took into a file bag and used a scanner to get electronic images.
How can I accurately segment these images?
I have tried to stick green paper on the cover of the scanner, but there are two problems with this approach:
Firstly, for FujiFilm rainbow film, there may be overlapping colors between green and film, which cannot be well separated.
Secondly, the method of using thresholds in the HSV space to obtain foreground results in low quality segmentation of image edges/boundary (ragged edges and possible green breakouts).

In view of this, I am wondering if it is possible to use template matching for cutout, as there are official provided samples, or manually scan a high-quality photo / manually design a perfect film based on the parameters provided on the official website,
I tried to perform line detection on the image and obtained the following results

and do the same with the scanned image

Although the detection results may not be perfect, from a human perspective, this detection result is sufficient to achieve a perfect match.
So how do templates and scanned images match?
